# Get information from .bcp file

Tags: database, bcp

I found a large `.bcp` (139GB) file with data (as can I read in readme). I need it to use it in my script and validate results.

The problem is... I don't know SQL yet. I have read that it is a database file. Is it possible to (in a simple way) open or rewrite that file to/as .csv? I found nothing in google about this (even .bcp extension is a little mystery ;D).
In post with a link to that file, was only short readme:

```
CREATE TABLE [SNPSubSNPLink]
(
[subsnp_id] [int] NULL ,
[snp_id] [int] NULL ,
[substrand_reversed_flag] [tinyint] NULL ,
[create_time] [datetime] NULL ,
[last_updated_time] [datetime] NULL ,
[build_id] [int] NULL ,
[comment] [varchar](255) NULL
)
```

Could someone advise me what to do to extract data from this file? Is it possible in pandas for example? Text editors shout that the file is too big.
I hope this question is not too stupid, and I did not miss any obvious information looking for a solution on the net.

Comment: You just want to import your file into a SQL Server ?

Comment: if this is the solution for getting all info from this file - Yes. But in this case, I need to create SQL Server and learn how to import it yes? That enough to get data? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open a bcp file, you can because it's just a simple text file. The problem with your file is the size, but it exists some tool like [Emeditor](https://www.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/large-file-support/files-up-to-248gb/) that allow you to open files up to 248Go.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for answer. Emeditor works great :)

Comment: Happy to help 